# This UML is missing the parameter, +DataRecorder(ostream &). How does that work?

Tags: uml, ostream

Here is the UML class diagram I am trying to understand:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|                 DataRecorder                |
-----------------------------------------------
|-out : ostream &                             |
-----------------------------------------------         
|+DataRecorder(ostream &)                     |
|+log(timestamp : Time, sensorName : string,  |
|sensorVoltage : double, sensorUnits : string)|
-----------------------------------------------
```

This is the line that is confusing me:

+DataRecorder(ostream &)

What is the parameter name for the reference to an ostream?

Comment: I talked with a programmer at work he thought that this might be a typo.  Is this just an incorrect UML diagram?

Comment: I got more clarification from another programmer. In a header file it is perfectly legal, however not preferred practice, to have function declaration with just the parameter types and leaving out the parameter name.  Once implemented you would need to include the parameter name.  Long story short, he also suspects that this is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter name is omitted. There is no way to tell from the diagram what it is.

Whether parameter names, types, or both, are displayed in a diagram depends on the tool. The names do not have to be included for the diagram to be UML-legal. What you've got here, with parameter names included in one method and omitted in another, is not something I've ever seen before though. It's pretty confusing and if it's intentional I'd say it's pretty poor quality.

Comment: Thanks.  That is inline with what my co-workers told me.  The UML was part of an assignment.  I messaged the instructor and he hasn't responded yet.